# How to create Custom Pagination Permalinks in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have an article with several pages in my wordpress blog. if for example i have the following link in my blog :

http://example.com/heartbreaking-photos
any idea how can i change the link of the second page from

http://example.com/heartbreaking-photos/2
to http://example.com/heartbreaking-photos/CUSTOM-STRING

CUSTOM-STRING aimed to be a custom title inside the page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this, you will need to do 2 things:

1. **Disable the default WordPress canonical redirect** - this is necessary, because WordPress will always redirect to the `/2/` page when it encounters the page parameter in the URL or query args.
2. **Add a custom rewrite rule to direct your custom title to the second page of your page** - this is essentially necessary to allow the link format that you want.

In terms of code, this is what you need (this is a working solution, I've just tested it locally):

```
// Removes the canonical redirection
remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );

// Add custom rewrite rules
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_custom_rewrite_rules' );
function my_add_custom_rewrite_rules() {
    // Slug of the target page
    $page_slug = 'heartbreaking-photos';

    // Page number to replace
    $page_num = 2;

    // Title you wish to replace the page number with
    $title = 'custom-string';

    // Add the custom rewrite rule
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^' . $page_slug . '/' . $title . '/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=' . $page_slug . '&page=' . $page_num, 'top'
    );
}
```

There are three things you might want to configure or change here:

1. `$page_slug` - this is the slug of your page, in your case this is `heartbreaking-photos`
2. `$page_num` - the number of your pagination page, in your case this is `2`
3. `$title` - the title you wish to use instead of your page number `2`.

Feel free to alter the code as you wish, or copy it to cover more additional cases, similar to this one.

**EDIT**

**Important**: Once you use the code, go to Settings > Permalinks and click the "Save Changes" button. This will rebuild your rewrite rules, and is necessary for the solution to work.

Hope that helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried your solution locally but couldn't get it to work. i tried two different themes just to be sure. i tried to add the code at the beginning and end of the `functions.php`. i also made sure to change the post slug..any idea what else can be different on my machine that prevent this thing from working..?

Comment: I've updated my answer, as I missed one small thing. After making changes to rewrite rules (as this code does), you should go to Settings > Permalinks and click the "Save Changes" button. This will make your changes actually work, because the rewrite rules will be regenerated. Let me know if you're having trouble once you try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this codex. Pass the arg and you will get page id, page title and use those
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

[image]

Or you can call page title by page id

```
$pagetitle= get_post_field( 'post_title', $page_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so basically you don't want to display the navigation link under the page (use css or modify the post template in the child theme) and add your custom link. If I understand it well:

Remove navigation links (depends on your theme, but basically):

```
.nav-links { display: none; }
```

You can add the custom link through function + custom fileds:

create a custom field, for example "my-url" in your post, see codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

add to your functions.php (in the child theme or in a custom site plugin):

```
function my_page_add_to_content( $content ) {

    if ( ! empty(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my-url', true ) ) {
       $content .= '<a href="'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my-url', true ).'">URL TEXT HERE</a>'
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_page_add_to_content' );
```