# wordpress pagination first page without number with custom argument

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to get WordPress Pagination. But when i hit first page it always redirect on page it self but here it redirect with page number

```
function pagination_bar( $custom_query ) {
    $total_pages  = $custom_query->max_num_pages;
    $current_page = isset( $_GET['page_num'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['page_num'] ) : 1;
   if ( $total_pages > 1 ) {
      echo '<strong>Page ' . $current_page . ' of ' . $total_pages . '</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;';
      echo paginate_links( array(
        'base'      => add_query_arg( 'page_num', '%#%' ),
        'format'    => '?page_num=%#%',
        'prev_text' => false,
        'next_text' => false,
        'current'   => $current_page,
        'total'     => $total_pages,
    ) );
  }}
```

I have pass custom page_num argument after page.

Comment: You can use jQuery, for example: onClick at first page, use preventDefault on click listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
add_filter( 'get_pagenum_link', 'wpse_78546_pagenum_link' );

function wpse_78546_pagenum_link( $link )
{
    return preg_replace( '~/page/(\d+)/?~', '?page_num=\1', $link );
}
```

Or you may also use this plugin. [Custom Pagination Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-pagination-permalinks/)

Hope this will helps you.

for more information,

- [How to create Custom Pagination Permalinks in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551634/how-to-create-custom-pagination-permalinks-in-wordpress/38671578)
- [Change permalink structure for pagination only](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78546/change-permalink-structure-for-pagination-only)

Comment: but i want to pass page_num argument after the url.

Comment: you can use page_num in the place of paged. but for that you need to format it

Comment: How can i fomat page_num

Comment: still argument passed page/2

Comment: hi, @DixitaDusara I again updated the answer. Pls, take a look.Hope this will helps you. :)